# What kind of math could I use, to reposition my hands, to my gun in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

Hi so I am making a recoil script for my First Person Shooter. I have the gun working pretty well. Here is my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GunRecoil : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Vector3 beforeRecoilRotation, rightBeforeRecoilRotation, leftBeforeRecoilRotation;
   //I have a separate script controlling maxRecoilX and recoil
    public float maxRecoilX = -0, recoilSpeed = 10, recoil = 0;
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject leftControl, rightControl, weapon;
    public bool once = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update

    void Recoiling()
    {
        //if recoil is present
        if (recoil > 0)
        {

            //make amount of recoil
            var maxRecoil = Quaternion.Euler(maxRecoilX, 0, 0);
            //move gun's rotation, according to recoil
            weapon.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(weapon.transform.localRotation, maxRecoil, Time.deltaTime * recoilSpeed);
            

            //subtract recoil by time.
            recoil -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            //make sure recoil is now zero
            recoil = 0;

            //make min recoil, based on starting position
            Quaternion minRecoil = Quaternion.Euler(beforeRecoilRotation);
            Quaternion minRecoilHandRight = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
            weapon.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(weapon.transform.localRotation, minRecoil, Time.deltaTime * recoilSpeed / 2);
            // rightControl.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(rightControl.transform.localRotation, minRecoilHandRight, Time.deltaTime * recoilSpeed / 2);

            maxRecoilX = 0;

        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //constantly run Recoiling

        Recoiling();
    

}




}
```

I also have hands for my gun. I want them to follow the rotation of the gun, to the rotation of my gun.
First I tried just applied the recoil to my hand. The results were close-ish, but not close enough. I used something like

```
var maxRecoilRight = Quaternion.Euler(maxRecoilX *5f, 0, 0);  

rightControl.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(weapon.transform.localRotation, maxRecoilRight, Time.deltaTime * recoilSpeed);
```

Here are the results:
[recoil One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsGN8.png)

I also tried using Fast IK: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/fast-ik-139972#reviews .
It didn't work, since I am using the parts of the arm in an animation
I also cannot parent the hands to the gun, since I am going to have to replace animations, and it might break my generic rig.

What kind of math could I use, to reposition my hands, to my gun in Unity? Please leave any suggestions for me. Thank you and have a good day/evening.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn off the animation of the hands while the recoil is ongoing, and use an IK solution for that time. Then when the recoil is finished you can turn it back on.

Comment: Alright. Do you know any that can work with a generic rig?

Comment: You could try Blend Trees to animate your hands depending on some recoil parameter of the gun.